# Generate Java classes from multiple XSDs with XJC

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I have two xsd files:

**base.xsd**:

```
<schema
  targetNamespace="http://www.myorg.com/base"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
<complexType name="NrmClass">
    ...
</complexType>
...
</schema>
```

**main.xsd** is a schema where we want to use a type from base.xsd

```
<schema
  targetNamespace="http://www.myorg.com/main"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xn="http://www.myorg.com/base">

<import namespace="http://www.myorg.com/base"/>
...
<element>
  <complexType>
    <complexContent>
      <extension base="xn:NrmClass">
...

      </extension>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
</element>
...
</schema>
```

When I try to compile both, I receive the following error:

```
> xjc base.xsd main.xsd
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xn:NrmClass' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 48 of file:/main.xsd
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to try specifying the file for the XSD you're importing, as in:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.myorg.com/base" schemaLocation="base.xsd"/>
```

This works well if you keep them side by side anyway. That way you can compile them in one operation.

If you want to run xjc separately (like they are built as separate modules), then you can use an episode file.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at "episodes":
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2006/09/separate_compil.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is definitely a good tip, but unfortunately even the example from the site is not working for me. I have posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532780/xjc-multiple-xsd-class-generation-using-episode