# XJC multiple XSD -> Class generation using "episode"

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I have two most simple xsd files.

a.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:a="A" targetNamespace="A">
  <complexType name="myType"/>
  <element name="root" type="a:myType"/>
</schema>
```

b.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="B" xmlns:a="A">
  <import namespace="A"/>
  <complexType name="extendedType">
    <complexContent>
      <extension base="a:myType"/>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
</schema>
```

We use the `myType` in b.xsd which is defined in a.xsd. The generation process consists of two steps using the "episode" feature.

```
> xjc -episode a.episode a.xsd
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
a\MyType.java
a\ObjectFactory.java
a\package-info.java

> xjc b.xsd -b a.episode
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'a:myType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 7 of file:/b.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

The first generation succeeds with a valid a.episode file, but the second fails. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example with Apache XMLBeans 2.5.0 and it worked with this command:

```
scomp -srconly a.xsd b.xsd
```